# textpos/textblock interacts badly with wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure, textpos

I want to position certain elements exactly in the corners of my page. With research, `textblock` seemed to be what I needed.

Here is a working example of that, before `wrapfigure` caused problems:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight}

\newcommand{\myblocks}
{
    \begin{textblock}{1}[0,-1](0,0)
        {\huge LEFT LEFT LEFT}
    \end{textblock}

    \begin{flushright}
    \begin{textblock}{1}[0,-1](0,0)
        {\huge RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT}
    \end{textblock}
    \end{flushright}
}

\newcommand{\mybox}
{
    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.3\textwidth}
        \subsection*{TEST}
        TEST WRAP FIGURE
        \begin{tabular}{|lrl|}
            \hline
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{wrapfigure}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{blank page}

\chapter{Alpha}
%\mybox
\myblocks
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 

\chapter{Beta}
%\mybox
\myblocks
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 

\end{document}
```

Here is how it renders. This is exactly as intended. (There is extra vertical padding due to the `-1` y-coordinate argument to the `textblock environment`, but otherwise the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` boxes are tightly in their respective corners.)

[image]

If we comment out the `\myblocks` invocations and uncomment `\mybox`...

```
\chapter{Alpha}
\mybox
%\myblocks
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 

\chapter{Beta}
\mybox
%\myblocks
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

[image]

Then these float-out tables also behave as intended, with text wrapping around them.

However, if I uncomment both of these, they both break.

```
\chapter{Alpha}
\mybox
\myblocks
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 

\chapter{Beta}
\mybox
\myblocks
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

Here's how it renders:

[image]

There are multiple problems:

- there is extra whitespace to the left of `LEFT` on both pages, it needs to be tight,
- the float-out table for "Alpha" is entirely missing,
- the float-out table for "Beta" is *above* the section heading, tight to the right-hand margin (as if it's inside the `textblock`)

I tried reversing the order of `\myblock` and `\mybox` invocations:

```
\chapter{Alpha}
\myblocks
\mybox
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 

\chapter{Beta}
\myblocks
\mybox
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

This also renders incorrectly:

[image]

The `LEFT` whitespace is gone but now neither table floats out to the edge nor lets the "lorem ipsum" text wrap around it. Moreover there is a warning in the compiler output:

> Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on in put line 43.
>
> Package wrapfig Warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 44

I don't understand these messages.

The intended end goal for this is that the "LEFT" and "RIGHT" placeholders will be generated to conform to the section heading. In other words, I will end up write something like this

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]
{
    \chapter{\gettitle{#1}}
    \drawcornerfeatures{#1}
}

\mysection{Alpha}
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.3\textwidth}
    ...
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum ...
```

This means *the code which generates the "LEFT" and "RIGHT" features must come before the float-out table or the lorem ipsum text.* In other words, the warning-emitting final example above is the correct order of events, and it although it draws the corners correctly, I need the tables to float out.

How can I get both of these effects to work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\par` at the end of the definition of `\mybox` and use thiscommand *after* `\myblocks`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight}

\newcommand{\myblocks}
{
    \begin{textblock}{1}[0,-1](0,0)
        {\huge LEFT LEFT LEFT}
    \end{textblock}

    {\raggedleft\begin{textblock}{1}[0,-1](0,0)
        {\huge RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT}
    \end{textblock}}
}

\newcommand{\mybox}
{%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.3\textwidth}
        \subsection*{TEST}
        TEST WRAP FIGURE
        \begin{tabular}{|lrl|}
            \hline
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            a & b & c \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{wrapfigure}\par\noindent
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{blank page}

\chapter{Alpha}
\myblocks
\mybox
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipisc-ing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\chapter{Beta}


\myblocks
\mybox%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipisc-ing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Two follow-ups, if you'd be so kind: why does `\par` make a difference, and what's with that "conflicting environment" warning? The warning is still there.

Comment: @spraff: Actually, if you test `\mybox` without `\par`, followed by *several* consecutive paragraphs, you'll  see it is placed near the 2nd paragraph. If you add a blank line between `\mybox` and the 1st paragraph, it works fine. In other words, it doesn't consider, for some reason, that the true 1st paragraph is the 2nd unless you add a blank line. Remember  `wrapfig` must be placed *before* a paragraph, so the simplest was to add a `\par` in the definition of `\mybox`.

Comment: @spraff: The conflicting environment problem is solved: it was due to `wrapfig` not liking to be near a list environment, and the `flushright` environment is implemented as a `trivlist`. So I replaced it with a  group including the `\raggedleft` directive. Also, while I was at it, I added `\noindent` at the end of the definition of `\mybox`since I think it looks nicer. Please test the new code.

Comment: `\raggedleft` and `\noindent` seem to work fine, thank you.